# What lanes are Annie suited to?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have just started maining Annie in League of Legends, and have been told numerous things, including 'Annie goes Mid!', 'Annie is support!' and 'Annie goes bottom!' Which ones are correct, if any?

In my own experience, Annie seems to work the best down bottom, but people keep telling me different things. Should I listen to others, as I am inexperienced, or to myself?

Basically, my question is "Which lanes are best for Annie?"

Comment: I don't think this is a very good question for this site, because whether a champion is "suited" for a specific lane is heavily opinion based. For example, Zyra was originally designed as a mid-lane mage, yet she sees most play as a support. Annie does well mid as a full AP mage, and in recent seasons she's also done very well as a heavy CC support bot lane. There's also no problem playing her top, though it is a little unconventional. It really depends on your playstyle and team comp.

Comment: Ah, do you think it could get shut dowm @MageXy?

Comment: Well, I voted to close for the reasons I've mentioned above. If enough other people agree, the question will be closed, yes. You might be able to prevent it if you can think of a way to reword your question to be less opinion-based.

Comment: @MageXy, its not particularly opinion based, all you have to do is point out the strengths and weaknesses of annie in each role to show which she is better suited for.

Comment: @Dragonrage Pointing out her strengths and weaknesses is great, as that is specific evidence that a player can draw their own conclusions from. However, which lane she's best in is still opinion. I looked at the answer you posted, and while I 100% agree with the pros and cons that you list, I disagree with your conclusion that mid is her strongest role. Using the exact same evidence you are using, my opinion is that support is her strongest role. As far as I'm concerned, if two people can draw two equally valid conclusions from the same evidence, the question is opinion based.

Comment: In any case, I already voted to close. If the votes don't agree, that's fine. It's why the system was put in place, after all.

Comment: In my opinion, asking for the *best* lane makes it opinion based, but asking for what lanes she works well in makes it [Good Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Hence I've edited the question.

Comment: Viability questions are strategy questions which are on-topic here as long as they are narrowed down. And this one's narrowed down to a specific champion which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dragonrage pointed out in his answer Annie can be played on pretty much any lane (even in jungle but I wouldn't recommend doing this in a serious game).

Annie's strongest lane depends on your personal playstyle but keep in mind that statistically her strongest lane is **[mid-lane](http://champion.gg/champion/Annie/Middle)**. I'm only covering Mid and Support here since the other lanes are purely situational.

**Annie mid**
Midlane is by far Annie's most played lane and as of writing this question she has the **[3rd-highest winrate of any midlane champion](http://champion.gg/statistics/?league=platplus#?sortBy=general.winPercent&order=descend&roleSort=Middle)**. One of the reasons she's extremely strong mid is her Q. If you last hit a minion with your Q you will get your mana back and the cooldown is reduced to 2 seconds instead of 4. This not only allows you to farm easily, it also builds stacks of your passive which can put a lot of pressure on your opponent (especially if they have no vision on your jungler).

Not only is her laning phase relatively strong, she also has a lot of snowballing potential and can set up ganks easily. Her passive stun also makes her great at ganks and roaming in general and midlane is the best lane to play a roamer since you can help your jungler, go bot or top.

Her only weakness is her lack of a gapcloser and once you burn your flash you might be very vulnerable against strong mid-gankers like Shaco or Lee-Sin.

As core items there are two options when playing mid: Full snowball AP with a Morello/Hextech Protobelt start or a slower scaling but safer Rod of Ages start.

**Annie Bot**
[**Botlane Annie**](http://champion.gg/champion/Annie/Support?league=platplus) isn't as strong as she used to be. She's played as either an AP or Tank  support but there are quite  a few weaknesses to her kit on bot

1. She is relatively low-range compared to other supporters
2. She is extremely squishy and will almost certainly die if she gets caught by CC (which makes counterpicking her easy)
3. She can get some serious mana-issues when playing aggressive since you shouldn't be stacking your stun by last hitting minons.
4. There are simply much stronger picks right now. Zyra does basically the same with delayed cc but more damage and range and other AP supporters have either more CC or more Heals/utility.

That being said she can still be a viable pick, especially on lower rankings. Support Annie is amongst the top 3 strongest supporters when it comes to level 6 burst. As soon as you hit 6 you can basically oneshot an ADC all by yourself. Up until then however you have to play carefully. It's still extremely important that you poke your enemies with auto attacks and spells but depending on the enemy support an error in positioning can mean a free kill for them since you are so fragile.

Keep in mind that support Annie will never come close to the gold of a midlane one. So your go-to build is Redemption into full-tank, effectively making you a stun-bot. Now if you are ahead you can risk it and go for a more AP heavy build but one slot should always be occupied by sightstone.

Now as I've already mentioned you might be a better support than mid player (or the other way around) which makes Annie automatically stronger in that lane (at least for you). Midlane and support have completely different carry playstyles and if you like her bot the most, go ahead and play her! It's certainly possible to reach a high rank with her on botlane. But keep in mind that her overall potential is greatest in playing mid. (At least until Riot decides to throw the meta around again)

Answer (score 4):

Annie is a mage. Mages primarily are played in the mid lane, as they tend to need solo experience and gold to get ahead. Annie particularly does well mid as she has a point and click stun, so she can easily roam top or bot and use her burst to help kill the side laners.

However, Annie can also be played support, as her stun gives her good utility to help in 2v2 fights. If she uses her W or R, she can potentially stun both enemy laners.

Some people also play her top, where she can do decently into some matchups as she has a fairly strong laning phase. To make up for not being able to roam as much as mid lane Annie, most people take teleport instead of ghost which is popular as a mid lane summoner spell.

So, in short, she can be played top, mid, or support, but in the current meta is strongest as a mid laner. Note: some people also play her adc because of her long auto attack range, but it is rare, and she is much weaker in that role than other standard adcs.

Comment: Ghost on Annie? As opposed to flash, or what? Flash/Ignite is the best combo on Annie, I'd think.

Comment: @mbomb007 ghost + Flash is common on mid Annie. Tp + Flash is typical for top

Comment: Must depend on the ranking of the player. I don't think I've ever seen ghost on Annie.